# aws / terraform Iam - inline

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

so here what I'm trying to do: is to create inline policies and attach it to an existing user?

aws_iam_user does create but instead, I would want to attach it to an existing user.

thanks

> ```
> resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
>   name = "arthur"
> }
>
> #Create Inline Policies for de-test 
> resource "aws_iam_user_policy" "arthur" {
>   name = "arthur inline"
>   user = aws_iam_user.user.name
>
>   policy = <<EOF
> {
>     "Version": "2012-10-17",
>     "Statement": [
>         {
>             "Sid": "s3inline",
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Action": [
>                 "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
>                 "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
>                 "s3:ListAccessPoints",
>                 "s3:GetBucketLocation"
>             ],
>             "Resource": "*"
>         },
>         {
>             "Sid": "s3inline",
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Action": [
>                 "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
>                 "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
>                 "s3:ListBucket",
>                 "s3:GetBucketAcl"
>             ],
>             "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::arthur-store"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> EOF
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
  name = "arthur"
}
```

To this:

```
data "aws_iam_user" "user" {
  user_name = "arthur"
}
```

---

Or, since you only need the name, there isn't much use to looking up the user at all, so you could just do this in the `aws_iam_user_policy`:

```
resource "aws_iam_user_policy" "arthur" {
  name = "arthur inline"
  user = "arthur"
  ...
```

Comment: data "aws_iam_user" "user" {
  user_name = "arthur"
}

Comment: what is data is for ? getting the user ?

Comment: i'm getting this error : Error: Error putting IAM user policy arthur-inline: MalformedPolicyDocument: Statement IDs (SID) in a single policy must be unique.
        status code: 400, request id: 96b22948-7850-4f68-ae69-ff99dc2dc6a3

Comment: Yes `data` is used for looking up existing things instead of creating them. As for the error, you need to do exactly what it says and give it unique `SID` values in the policy.

Comment: in this usecase adding several users to a group policies ? how should i proceed?

Comment: It sounds like you need to add users to a group, and add the policies to the group. I think this is going beyond the initial question you had and may need to be posted as a different question including more details.